# Java - Private scope

Tags: java, scope

In JS, you can do for example:

```
(function() {
    var x = 7;
})();

console.log(x);
```

That will log undefined since x is only defined in it's own little scope.

What's the original/best/normal way to do the same thing in java?

Not this because I think it looks pretty ugly:

```
...
public static void main(String[] args) {
    do {
       int x = 7;
    } while (false) {}

    System.out.println(x);
}
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why downvote? Please explain exactly why

Comment: Not enough research effort.

Comment: Really if you though so, you would have added that comment earlier.

Comment: @what exactly are you asking? your question has a title that says private scope and in the box you are asking about variable scopes?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is an interpreted language, so you will get these kind of errors on runtime. In difference Java is a compiled language, so the compiler catches this kind of error in compile time.

It is impossible to get this error in Java programs on runtime.

Comment: @Murplyx the one you have there already should be enough to get an error for a variable scope

Comment: k but is there any ***smooother*** way to do it than a ugly while loop that isn't even a loop?

Comment: @Murplyx You want a smooth way to get an error?! May I ask what for?

Comment: Its not bout the ror its bout getting the same code in java as in js

Comment: It is not possible, as I stated. Both languages follow a completely different concept.

Answer (score 0):

If you want x to be private then u can declare it private as
//you can give any access specifier if u dont want x to be private

```
private int x;

and can initialize it later 
as

public static void main(String[] args) {
    do {
       x = 7;
    } while (false) {}

    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Your code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        do {
          int x = 7;
        } while (false) {}

        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

This will throw undefined exception because that variable is defined inside the do and thus its scope is only till that while do loop and thus it cant be accessed outside.

Comment: He asked for method-scope variables, not class fields.